# Derivative of function defined as Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have to find all partial derivatives of:

$$ f(x,y,z) = \int_{\cos x + \sin y}^{z} e^{tz} dt $$

I easily get confused with all this variables, but the idea is to use The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Let $s =  \cos(x) $ 
$$ - \int_{z}^{s + sin(y)}  e^{tz} dt \longrightarrow \frac{df}{dx} = -e^{s + sin(y)z} \cdot (s + sin(y))' = e^{(\cos(x)+\sin(y))z} \cdot \sin(x) $$

Is this approach right? Thanks!

EDIT_1: I can do the same for $\frac{df}{dy}$ but how do I do it for $\frac{df}{dz}?$

EDIT_2: What if I had to find $df(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{3}, 0)$? Calculating the pratial derivatives respect to x and y, I obtain $df(\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{3}, 0) = (1,-\frac{1}{2}, ?)$. The problem is when I use the approach suggested by $user3154270$  I get some terms like $z^{-1}$ and the limes doesn't exist. But the result should be $\frac{5}{8}$.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

I think you only have to calculate the integral. So 
$$
- \int_{cos x+sin y }^z e^{tz} d t = -\Big[\frac{1}{z}e^{tz}\Big]_{t=cos x+sin y }^{t=z} = \frac{1}{z}e^{z(cos x+sin y)}-e^{z^2}
$$
And then you calculate the partial derivates.

Comment: I Edited my question, you can take a look to see what I mean